# Is there a way for a local HTML page to trigger a Python Tkinter GUI at the end of the file?

Tags: python, html, tkinter

I created an HTML page and I would like to attach my python tkinter program (that generates a GUI) at the end of that page. Perhaps a button that would trigger my IDLE. It doesn't have to be embedded within the HTML but I do want my HTML to be able to automate the IDLE environment and trigger the python program. Is this possible?

Comment: most likely it is possible using javascript I think, because it should be possible to access local files with javascript through html, otherwise You can't run python in browser also as far as I understand You want to have a button that starts Your GUI locally?

Comment: If you load the HTML file directly from a browser, you cannot execute any application in your local machine due to security.  If you load the page via HTTP, you can send a request to *server* to execute something in *server side* (it may be in local machine as well).

Comment: @Matiiss yes locally on my pc.

Comment: @acw1668 thank you for your response. how do you suggest I can accomplish this?

Comment: See [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67177112/python-flask-getting-an-error-when-server-shutdown-is-declined) that running web server and tkinter in same machine.